# Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to clean up my styles by using a StyleSheet, but I can't seem to get it to work. I believe the error (seen below) is caused when I attempt to create a StyleSheet (`const styles =  EStyleSheet.create`.
*Note I am using [react-native-extended-stylesheet](https://github.com/vitalets/react-native-extended-stylesheet)*  However this is not the problem. This also happens with react-native's stylesheet. 
This a picture of the error: [image: error]

This this my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import {
  View,
  Text,
  Button,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  TouchableOpacity
} from "react-native";

export default class Login extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.wrapper}>
        <Text>Login screen </Text>

        <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={styles.loginContainer}>

          <TextInput
          placeholder="username or email"
          placeholderTextColor='whitesmoke'
          style={styles.input}
          />

          <TextInput
          placeholder="password"
          secureTextEntry
          placeholderTextColor='whitesmoke'
          style={styles.input}
          />

          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginbutton} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Grades")}>
            <Text style={{
              textAlign: 'center',
              color: "whitesmoke",
              fontWeight: '700',
            }}>
            Login
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

        </KeyboardAvoidingView>

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  loginContainer: {
    paddingHorizontal: 9,
    backgroundColor: "red"
  },

  input: {
      paddingHorizontal: 10,
      marginBottom: 10,
      color: '#f1c40f', //sunflower color
      backgroundColor: '#3498db',
    },

 logo: {
    width: 231,
    height: 231
  },

  wrapper: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center" 
  }

});
```

Here is my app.js.

```
import React from "react";
import { Font } from "expo";

import { Root } from "./app/router";
import { FontError } from "./app/components/fontError";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    fontLoaded: false
  };
  async componentDidMount() {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      Arial: require("./app/resources/Arial.ttf")
    });
    this.setState({ fontLoaded: true });
  }
  render() {
    if (!this.state.fontLoaded) return <FontError/>;
    return <Root />;
  }
  // ...
}
```

My root component is router.js, I am using react-navigation.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation";

import {
  Login,
  Grades,
} from "./screens";

export const Root = createStackNavigator({
  Login: {screen: Login},
  Grades: {screen: Grades},

});
```

Feel free to ask me to append any additional information.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: You are missing a comma after StyleSheet in your import statement. Is it the same in your code or just in your question

Comment: Whoops. That's just in my question

Comment: please add app entering component of the your app e.g. App.js

Comment: Sorry for the wait. I added in my app.js and router.js. (I am using react-navigation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix my error I just re-cloned the repo and added back in all the code I wrote.
Thankfully I didn't push this error to the master branch.
This fixed the error.

*note in the process I got rid off react-native-extended-stylesheet, so it might have been cause of error.